Export Eclipse Scout table rows as a CSV file and let user download the file
I would like to export the rows (all rows, as well as just filtered rows) of an Eclipse Scout table as a CSV file. And after creation of this file, I would like the user to be able to download it.
I see in the ITable interface of the framework, a method called exportTableRowsAsCSV, but I cannot find examples of its usage.
Thanks a lot for your kind assistance.
JDaniel

This function is not available out-of-the-box, but you can easily build it yourself using the following utilities:

TableUtility to convert rows and columns to a data matrix.
CsvHelper to generate CSV output from the data matrix.
IDesktop#openUri to send the output as a downloadable file to the browser.

// Select data to export
Table table = getTable();
List<ITableRow> rows = table.getFilteredRows();
List<IColumn<?>> columns = table.getColumnSet().getVisibleColumns();

// Convert to data matrix (with column headers)
Object[][] csvData = TableUtility.exportRowsAsCSV(rows, columns, true, false, false);

// Write data to byte array
CsvHelper csvHelper = new CsvHelper(NlsLocale.get(), ";", "\"", "\n");
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  csvHelper.exportData(csvData, writer, null, false, null, false);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  throw BEANS.get(DefaultRuntimeExceptionTranslator.class).translate(e);
}

// Download as file
BinaryResource binaryResource = new BinaryResource("export.csv", out.toByteArray());
IDesktop.CURRENT.get().openUri(binaryResource);


Thank you so much for your assistance. It worked!! I will accept your response as the answer. However, I have another question concerning how dates are written to the csv file..A date like 2024-10-09 is written as Wed Oct 09 00:00:00 CEST 2024. Do you know how I can get date in the format YYYY-mm-dd in the csv file?

Probably easiest would be to convert the Date objects in csvData to Strings manually using SimpleDateFormat. Alternatively, you might be able to use the columnTypes argument of the exportData() function. It seems to support a special syntax for specifying the format pattern (see JavaDoc of CsvHelper#getFormat).
